# Generate textbox dynamicaly without ng-repeat and onclick get All textboxvalues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropzone.js

I have requirement where I need to insert text box below every thumbnail. I'm using it with angularjs.

I have already added delete link which on click calls API to delete file from server . but if i will add text box I need to send All Text Box value on click of some button I need to send text box value of all thumbnail .

I am not using ng-repeat here to in ng-mode what should I use?
How can I get all text box value or in ng-model what should i use?

```
myDropzone.on("success", function(file, response) {
    obj = JSON.parse(response);
    var removeLinkUrl = Dropzone.createElement('<span class="server_file">' + obj.delete_url + '</span>');
    file.previewElement.appendChild(removeLinkUrl);
});
```

**Thumbnail Template**

```
<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
    <div class="dz-details">
    <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
    <div class="dz-size" data-dz-size></div>
        <img data-dz-thumbnail />
    </div>
    <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>
    <div class="dz-success-mark"><span>✔</span></div>
    <div class="dz-error-mark"><span>✘</span></div>
    <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try to use $compile . 

JS - 



 $scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}, {id: 'choice2'}, {id: 'choice3'}];
    $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
        var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
        $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice' +newItemNo});
    };

    $scope.showAddChoice = function(choice) {
       return choice.id === $scope.choices[$scope.choices.length-1].id;
    };
```

### HTML

```
<div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
    <label for="choice" ng-show="showChoiceLabel(choice)">Choices</label>
        <button ng-show="showAddChoice(choice)" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add another  choice</button>
    <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="Enter a restaurant name">
</div>
```